# How to echo images from a separate directory?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have now worked out how to echo images from MySQL.

Now I want to work out a way to echo images from a separate directory?...In this case WordPress.

My goal is to grab any posts on my WordPress blog which have a featured image and echo them onto a page of my choice.

So here is what I have so far:

```
echo "
<div class=\"pagination\" style=\"display:inline\"><ul style=\"background-color:#\"><li><div     class=\"span3_search\"><h2><a href='$link'><b>$title</b></a></h2><br><a href='$link'><img     id=\"result_img\" src=\"$image\" /></a><br /><p>$description</p><br />
<a href='$link'>$link<br /><br /></a><p></div></li></ul></div>
";
```

how do I echo a image src which is the source to where my featured images are.

i.e

```
echo "<img src="PHP WHICH SAYS GRAB WORDPRESS FEATURED IMAGES FROM THIS DIRECTORY etc">";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the image of the path and then append a new path;

```
$image = explode('/');
$image = $image[count($image)];

echo 'mynew/path/toimage/'.$image;
```

To see al parts of the path, do;

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($images);
echo '</pre>;
```